# *Complete* recipe for installing single-boot Linux

Tags: mac, unix, efi, grub

What is a **complete** recipe for installing a modern (18/20/22) **single-boot** Ubuntu LTS on a Mac (Mac Mini, iMac, MacBook, ...)?

My objective from selecting Ubuntu is to have a local Linux machine that mirrors an AWS instance—for experiments that iron out differences (Docker, etc) between developing on macOS and deploying on Linux. Any distro (Ubuntu, CentOS, Debian, Fedora, Suse, Arch, in this order) is fine. For Docker etc use cases, they will all be identical.

Single-boot should be simple, particularly for those who anyway have a more recent Mac. A recipe for dual-boot (macOS + Linux) would also be good.

Comment: Looks like great content for an answer and we can make the question easy to search by summarizing the ask.

Comment: @bmike I see your point. I'll tell you what: If you identify the one or two points that are tripping me in the recipe above, and post a one- or two-liner answer that does the trick, I'll maintain your answer to make it a self-contained answer (and perhaps simplify the question afterwards to be a one- or two-liner).

Comment: Aah. I thought you were working this up as the way to to it. No worries. We can host both versions. You’re not wrong. It’s a mater of preference how to ask. I like to make the question short and post a partial answer, but that is like/preference, not mandatory.

Comment: My  15" Macbook Pro late 2013 has thermal issues with Linux. This article helps for disabling GPE events. Used with conjunction of mbpfan and/or macfanctld: https://medium.com/@racter/how-to-install-ubuntu-16-04-on-a-retina-macbook-11-2-74e7779c0e47

Comment: @bmike You're right, of course. It's much better as a proper Q&A. Here is my attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to boot from the flash drive after you have installed Ubuntu. Instead, you need to boot to GRUB installed on your internal drive. This can be done by pressing the <kbd>esc</kbd> key **once** immediately after selecting Ubuntu from the Start Menu. (I assume here you installed for a UEFI boot.) It took me a couple tries before getting the hang of it. Once booted to GRUB, you can add `nomodeset`, then proceed to boot to Ubuntu.

First thing I would do is turn the GRUB menu back on. Below are the steps to do so.

1. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a Terminal window.
2. Enter the command `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.
3. Change `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`.
4. Save and exit the editor.
5. Enter the command `sudo update-grub`.

To add `nomodeset` to GRUB, follow the same steps as above, except change step 3 to the following.

3. Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`.

### References

- [KernelBootParameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters)
- [Skip Grub at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704642/skip-grub-at-boot/704728)
- [Simple configuration handling](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html)
- [How to set NOMODESET and other kernel boot options in grub2](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)

Comment: It really is as simple as you describe, which makes me wonder how difficult it would be to suggest a patch so that a future Ubuntu (there is no point in adding to the existing already formidable number) release would work on some subset of Macs.

Comment: If you are installing for a dual boot with macOS, then the GRUB menu is enabled by default. So, you do not have to press the ESC key. When Ubuntu is the only operating system, then the GRUB menu by default is hidden.

Comment: Brilliant! I began my *quest* to install LinuxMint on my *late 2011 17" MBP* yesterday, but it failed - perhaps due to not knowing to press the `esc` key, perhaps something else? I burned an iso to USB using `balenaEtcher`, boot fm USB by holding `option` key. I get a bit of text, but it never leads to anything. I was trying to install to a new, blank SSD - is that what you did?

Comment: I gave up on LinuxMint - at least temporarily to try your Ubuntu recipe. The `nomodeset` option seems to be a key to making this work. I say this 'cause LinuxMint "compatibility mode" gave me console output for a bit, but stopped at a line that *sounded like* adjusting the video config. However: After starting the Ubuntu install, it says "This computer currently has no detected operating systems". I've re-thought the single-boot idea, and for now would prefer to retain my `High Sierra` install - any thoughts? Shouldn't Ubuntu recognize that macos is installed?

Comment: @Seamus: I believe a tested my answer using VirtualBox. In other words, I never actually installed any version of Linux on a physical drive.

Comment: Oh - well that's quite different. FWIW, I've gotten the Ubuntu install started, but even after creating a new partition (shrunk the APFS *container* & added FAT partition), Ubuntu ***still*** wants to grab the entire drive. I *think* the correct choice is *Do Something Else* in the installer, but that *something else* is going to require some more research :) FWIW, I also installed `rEFInd` - it seems very polished &nicely done!

Comment: The *something else* is the only choice for a dual boot with macOS already installed. You can not create a partition with a ext4 volume, swap space or a LVM without this choice. (Although, I believe Ubuntu only requires adding a single Linux partition containing an ext4 volume.) BTW, rEFInd is not necessary to boot Linux on your Mac, but you can use rEFInd if you want. For an example, see [Ubuntu 18.04 installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112798/ubuntu-18-04-installation).

Answer (score 1):

**This is an ongoing recipe; it is work-in-progress**

#### Recipe for Installing Single-Boot Ubuntu on a Mac

- Download the Ubuntu [ISO](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Download [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). Use Etcher to prepare a USB flash.
- Insert flash. Press <kbd>Option</kbd> before chime. Choose EFI. [Puzzle: Why do *two* instances of EFI appear, both from the installation flash disk?]
- Press 'e'. Replace `quiet splash` with `quiet splash nomodeset`.
- Install Ubuntu on Mac's disk.

After less than 10 minutes we're now essentially done. The most important remaining to-do: setting up a wireless (Broadcom) driver.

Attempts:

- [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077020/1020871) recipe for setting up the wifi router doesn't work. The 'additional driver' tab is empty.
- [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/470347/1020871) recipe works, but it's necessary to restart after each trial, and the first restart took a while—it appears to initiate an update that lingers after the command-line prompt returns. Short version: Control-Option-T (terminal). `sudo apt-get update`. Do something else. Reboot. Perhaps wait again. `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`. Reboot.
- Find the machine's IP address on the local network by running `sudo apt-get net-tools` [followed by](https://serverfault.com/a/46647) `/sbin/ifconfig -a`.
- [Install/launch](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-ssh-on-ubuntu-18-04/) ssh server daemon by running `sudo apt install openssh-server`.

Booting from the Mac's disk will hang at the splash screen. The `nomodeset` addition needs to be saved. *[There may well be a quick exit at this point for a headless Linux instance (that's what one gets from AWS anyway). But let's keep that for a sequel. In this case we're after a working (KDE, etc) set up.*

The following is from [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/38782/1020871)
[three](https://askubuntu.com/a/941322/1020871)
[recipes](https://askubuntu.com/a/757130/1020871).

**Introduce `nomodeset` to the boot script**

- Boot once again from flash (press 'option'; press 'e'; adjust 'nomodeset').
- This time abort installation ('quit'). Launch the terminal (pressing the nine-dot icon brings up a search bar).
- Use `gparted` (How to reveal this on the command line? `mount`? `parted -l`? `fdisk /dev/sda`?) to determine the `ext4` partition. Say it's `/dev/sda2`.
- `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&`, `sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&`, `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&`, `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`. [Something is wrong here. Still working on a complete, self-contained recipe.]
- `sudo chroot /mnt` (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/941322/1020871)). [Something is wrong here. Still working on a complete, self-contained recipe.]
- `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
- Add `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.
- `sudo update-grub`.

The output at this last step is:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub`
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0.23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1. Check your device.map.
done
```

Still to-do: telling `sudo update-grub` to use `/dev/sda2`.

Wondering: would using rEFInd simplify the recipe above?

What is briefer, to use rEFInd or not to use it? I understand that the reason for the existence of rEFInd is to enable a dual-boot linux set up on a Mac. But if just single-boot linux is sought, does introducing rEFInd make the recipe simpler or more complicated?