# how to install ubuntu and triple boot with high sierra and legacy booting win10 with dual disk drive?

Tags: macos, windows, partition, unix, multi-boot

I have a mac mini (5,1) with two disk drives, right now one is installed with macOS High Sierra, one is installed with Windows 10 as shown below:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:               Windows_NTFS System                  104.9 MB   disk0s1
   2:               Windows_NTFS Windows                 499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                       0x27                         602.9 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         127.8 GB   disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +127.8 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume macOS                   32.7 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.8 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.1 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk2s4
```

I want to partition some space(40G) on the disk which macOS is installed(disk1) to install ubuntu 20.04 server, and triple boot all three OS without install third party boot manager, what should be the right steps to do this properly, or is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: This installation procedure was tested by using VirtualBox. Both High Sierra (macOS 10.13.6) and 64 bit Windows 10 (1909) installers were used to create the partitions. Nether macOS or Windows were installed prior to installing Ubuntu Server.

### Create a Linux Partition

The output from the macOS command `diskutil list disk1` is shown below.

```
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         127.8 GB   disk1s2
```

To create the Linux partition, first you need to calculate the new size for the APFS container partition. Since you want 40 GB for linux, the new size would be as follows.

```
127.8 GB - 40 GB = 87.8 GB
```

The macOS command to create the unformatted linux partition is given below.

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s2 87.8G %linux% none 0
```

The result is shown below.

```
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2          87.8 GB   disk1s2
   3:           Linux Filesystem                          40.0 GB   disk1s3
```

### Install Ubuntu Server

> Note: I assume you following Ubuntu's instructions for creating the bootable Ubuntu Server USB flash drive or burned a DVD.

1. When the image below appears, highlight `Update to the new installer`. Next, press <kbd>return</kbd>.

   > Note: To get a better view of an image, click on the image or open the linked image in a new window.

   [image]
2. When the image below appears, select `Custom storage layout`, then highlight `Done`, as shown below. Next, press <kbd>return</kbd>.

   [image]
3. Highlight `partition 3  existing, unused`, as shown below. Next, press <kbd>return</kbd>.

   [image]
4. Highlight `Edit`, as shown below. Next, press <kbd>return</kbd>.

   [image]
5. Select `ext4` as the format.

   > Note: Mount should appear as `/`.

   Highlight `Save`, as shown below. Next, press <kbd>return</kbd>.

   [image]
6. Highlight `Done`, as shown below. Next, press <kbd>return</kbd>.

   [image]
7. Highlight `Continue`, as shown below. Next, press <kbd>return</kbd>.

   [image]
8. Proceed with the installation.

### Notes

I encountered synchronization issues when booting to the operation system. Often the prompts for input occur before all the messages have been output.

### References

[*Complete* recipe for installing single-boot Linux](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376977/complete-recipe-for-installing-single-boot-linux)
[Dual-Booting OS X or macOS with Linux without rEFInd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831161/dual-booting-os-x-or-macos-with-linux-without-refind)
[What is the difference between grubx64 and shimx64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342365/what-is-the-difference-between-grubx64-and-shimx64)

Comment: I'm sorry for this late reply. Thanks for this detailed answer and I'll accept your answer. I've figured it out, more or less the same as your answer, the interface of the installation seems different, for example, there is no indication of update of the installer at the beginning. Anyway, I install successfully. Only remain issues are change the icon and name of the boot menu.